# $q.all promise depends on result of another promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have three nested promises which I want to turn into a $q.all call.

It looks something like this.

```
ds.saveData(data).then(function (result1){
    someOtherVar = result1.Id;
    ds.saveSomethingDependant(someOtherData).then(function (result2){
        ds.saveAThirdThing(someOtherVar).then(function (result3){
            ns.notify();
        }, function (error){
            ns.error(error);
        });
    }, function (error){
        ns.error(error);
    });
}, function (error) {
    ns.error(error);
});
```

Wow what a mess. My concern is where I edit someOtherVar. Is there some other way to do this so I don't have nested promises but still edit data after one promise? Nested promises are a nightmare to do jasmine tests on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `result2` has a dependency on `result1`, you'll have to wait until the latter's ready before executing the former. But, you can still use `$q.all` if the first and third operations aren't dependent on one another:

```
$q.all({
  saveData: ds.saveData,
  saveAThirdThing: ds.saveAThirdThing
}).then(function(results) {
  /* expect(results).toEqual({
   *   saveData: result1,
   *   saveAThirdThing: result3
   * });
   */
  return saveSomethingDependent(results.saveData.Id);
}).then(function(result2) {
  // all done
  ns.notify();
}, function(error) {
  // something in the chain above failed
  ns.error(error);
});
```

We're taking advantage of the fact that you can return a promise from a resolve handler, which will then resolve that promise before sending it to the next promise in the chain (and thereby avoiding nesting).

You can also simplify somewhat by putting your reject handler at the end of the chain, since you're handling all errors in the same way in your example.

Answer (score 3):

let's say easy and readable method chain

```
var saveDate = function(data) {
  return ds.saveDate(data);
}

var saveOtherthings = function(result) {
  return $q.all([ds.saveSomethingDependant(result.id), ds.saveAThirdThing(result.id)])

}

saveDate(data)
  .then(saveOtherthings)
  .then(function(result) {
    ns.notify();
  }, function(error) {
    ns.error(error);
  });
```